# Postfix Masquarade Name *and* Email address

Tags: email, postfix

At the moment, I have a RHEL6 monitoring server that sends out emails with postfix. Originally it was sending them out as `user@host.localhost`.

I've used the mapping file `/etc/postfix/generic` to get the emails sent out now as `monitoringuser@domain.com`, however when the email client receives the email, there is no longer a name attached to the email address.

Originally, with the default configuration, emails would come in with the sender as this -
`user <user@host.localhost>`
Now when I recevied the emails, they come in with just the email address -
`monitoringuser@domain.com` - there is no longer a name displayed.

I've googled and looked at docs but can't seem to figure out the way to do this.

Is there a way for postfix to fix that or append the name that I want ? Or is it up to the script calling `mail` to append a name to the sender ?

Comment: Just a guess: does `user` exist as a real user (`/etc/passwd`) on the system with a GECOS field of `user` and maybe there is no `monitoringuser` entry in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: user does exist, but monitoringuser doesnt. So maybe if I add a monitoringuser into /etc/passwd, it would add a name ?

Comment: I would try to do so. `user` has to come from somewhere, either stripping the address from `@` onwards, or (more likely IMHO) from the GECOS field (5th, comment field in `/etc/passwd`), did you check the value of the field?

Comment: I've updated /etc/passwd but still don't get the name when receiving emails from the `monitoringuser`

Comment: Did you include the gecos field? What script is sending the mail? Can you share that?

Comment: Did you mean the gecos field in /etc/passwd ? If you did then yes. I'm not at work now but I'll post up the relevant line when I can.

Comment: The relevant line that sends the email in the script is this - `mail -s "A $SEV alarm has occurred on $SERVER (Model Name=$MNAME)(Model Type=$MTYPE)" $RCVRS < /tmp/set_alarm.$PID`  -- Also it seems that sending the mail manually from the `monitoringuser` account works, but the script doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the GECOS field needs to be filled in for the original user, not the user that the emails are being masqueraded to appear to be from.